# How to add bcc on the email notification on forgot password

Tags: solspace, solspace-user

I would like to send bcc email to myself when user forgot password (reset password). I have solspace user add-on module. I only see 1 email address could put in. http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/forgot_password/#email

Does anyone know how to send notification to multiple email address (i.e. cc or bcc) when user forgot password. Thanks

Comment: I totally agree with **foamcow** that this is not good idea. Not secure. May be you can tell why do you need it? May be we can advice another solution?

Comment: The issue has been taken care. The reason that I need to bcc to myself is I could keep tracking who reset password. When user come back to me(admin) said he/she hasn't received any reset email after request reset. I could show user the reset email has been sent out.

Comment: I don't think that is right way to investigate it - if you have cases like this, it's better to check mail server logs.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I think sending a password reset email to a cc or (worse) bcc is a huge security and privacy concern. As a user I certainly would not be very happy about that happening.

There is a big difference between a Super Admin being able to log in to a user's account via the control panel and that Admin knowing a user's password (which may also be used elsewhere). It's for this reason that you a Super Admin cannot ever "see" a user's password.

Even within a "trusted" system, i.e. a private network, allowing other users to have the potential to change a password removes any credibility to any audit of activity. Basically, if more than one person could change a password you can no longer say who was accessing the system when something happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, sending a forgot password email to a CC'ed or BCC'ed address isn't possible. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

There are no hooks in User to add this functionality either. A hypothesis here, but perhaps there is a 3rd-party add-on that hooks up to email sending timed well enough enough to add a CC or BCC to the sent email. However, I highly doubt this exists.

Lastly, and this is just another idea, you could *perhaps* send a separate email using javascript/jQuery and Ajax, but you will need javascript/jQuery knowledge for that. In this situation, you could call a separate template (perhaps using something like http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/email-from-template) which triggers the sending of an email (perhaps using something like http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/email-from-template) to a specified address *before* triggering the actual forgot password form submission. Obviously the email content would be different, and the email woulnd't be CC'ed or BCC'ed. Tutorials for calling a separate URL before submitting a form are likely plenty available on the net.